# Splitting Phone numbers

Tags: php, arrays, explode

Got code below:

```
// $partInfo has data filled in
// $partinfo['BusinessPhone'] = '-567-5675678-'
// $billdata *should* have data filled in
// $billdata['BillingInfo']['telephone'] = ''
$telephone = explode('-', $billdata['BillingInfo']['telephone']);
echo "<!-- Telephone: ". print_r($telephone, true)." -->";
```

produces:

```
<!-- Telephone: Array
(
    [0] => 
)
-->    

// if billdata billinginfo telephone is blank
if(count($telephone)==0) {
  $telephone = explode('-', $partinfo['BusinessPhone']);
}
echo "<!-- Telephone2: ". print_r($partinfo['BusinessPhone'], true)." -->";
```

produces:

```
<!-- Telephone2: -567-5675678- -->
```

But...

```
echo "<!-- Telephone3: ". print_r($telephone, true)." -->";
```

produces:

```
<!-- Telephone3: Array
(
    [0] => 
)
-->
```

I suppose that since count($telephone) returns 1 instead of an empty array, that that's where I'm going wrong. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: To do what? What is your question?

Comment: What's the query? Where's $billdata is defined? Why not using $partInfo?

Comment: `var_dump($billdata); var_dump($partinfo);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the **Return Values** section of the [PHP documentation for explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

> If delimiter is an empty string (""), explode() will return FALSE. **If delimiter
>   contains a value that is not contained in string** and a negative limit is used, then an
>   empty array will be returned, otherwise **an array containing string will be returned**.

So what's happening is that since `$billdata['BillingInfo']['telephone'] = ''` contains an empty string, which does not contain the given delimiter, it is returning an array containing the given string.

What you can do instead is:

```
$telephone = false;
if ($billdata['BillingInfo']['telephone']) {
    $telephone = explode('-', $billdata['BillingInfo']['telephone']);
}

if (!$telephone) {
    $telephone = explode('-', $partinfo['BusinessPhone']);
}
```